# Flutter: shadow color of the drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-drawer

I want to use [Drawer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html).

When the Drawer unfolds - as you can see in the video in the link - the background or the rest of window is shadowed to let the user focus on the drawer.

[image]

I feel that the shadow is very dark, is there any way to change the color of the shadow?
The documentation for the [Drawer class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Drawer-class.html) lists several parameters such as shadowColor but it seems to be outdated since the Drawer class only takes the parameter

```
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.shape,
    this.width,
    this.child,
    this.semanticLabel,
```

Any idea or trick?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the overlay color of the `Drawer` doesn't have to do with the `Drawer`, but rather the `Scaffold` itself. You need to set [`drawerScrimColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/drawerScrimColor.html) to `transparent`:

> The color to use for the scrim that obscures primary content while a drawer is open.

```
Scaffold(
  drawerScrimColor: Colors.transparent,
```